# Developing a concept throughout multiple questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

My method of developing a concept to a working piece of <s>plotdevice</s> technology

### ___________________________________________________

Original concept
       ||
       /
(repeat untill  there are little to no flaws):

---

---

Flawsearching (done by the aswerers)
||
/
Proposing possible solutions (done by me)

---

---

### ____________________________________________________

**Should I do it, or it counts as duplicate, or against the rules?**

*everything is so gray in here*

Comment: To be fair, it isn't all gray... it's also shades of cyan, puce, infrared, and octarine. Gray implies a sort of fog that no matter how much you stay in it, you'll never see clearly. The others are more subtle shades of reality that do actually seem to become clearer if you give it time. Worldbuilding turns out to be complex, and it gets tricky to make sure the site stays useful. Certainly more complex than I would've guessed a year ago when I started working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each question should (1) stand on its own and (2) not change out from under answers it's already received.  So, if you ask a question and learn from the answers that one of your core assumptions was wrong, you *shouldn't* edit that question to change it and instead *should* ask a new question.  Or, if you ask question A and get an answer that you want to develop further, instead of asking the author for lots of additional information that wasn't part of the original question, ask a new question B and explain what you already know and what you're trying to do.

Sequences of questions like that are fine.  (I've done it, and I'm far from the only one.)  It's helpful to link to the previous questions, but make sure the new question contains all the information that someone would need to answer -- offer links, but don't assume people will always follow them.